# Running a exe file on windows server using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am using the below ansible playbooks but it's not installing it, can anyone help?

```
- name: Install Firefox
  hosts: wintestserverchandra

  **tasks:**
  - name: Firefox
    raw: d:\install\firefox.exe
```

I used win_msi as well but no go.

Comment: Please add the error ansible gives you with `-vvvv` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to install Firefox via Ansible.

Just use the [chocolatey Firefox package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Firefox) and install it with the [win_chocolatey module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_chocolatey_module.html):

```
  - name: Install Firefox via chocolatey
    win_chocolatey:
      name: Firefox
```